# Iterating through list of list without knowing number of inner lists

Tags: python, list, zip, python-itertools

I have a list of list:

```
x = [[1,2,3], [4,2], [5,4,1]]
```

I want to traverse the elements in the inner list sequentially and get:

```
1 4 5
2 2 4
3 None 1
```

I've tried this but I couldn't get the last line:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3], [4,2], [5,4,1]]
>>> a, b, c = x
>>> for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
...     print i,j,k
... 
1 4 5
2 2 4
```

**Given that *I don't know how many inner lists* are there how do i do achieve the desired result?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to pad the shorter sublists:

```
for t in izip_longest(*x):
    print t
```

Note the use of `*x` and `t` to deal with an unknown number of sublists.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
x = [[1,2,3], [4,2], [5,4,1]]
for i in izip_longest(*x):
    print i

(1, 4, 5)
(2, 2, 4)
(3, None, 1)
```